# terminal shows import error no module named site when input vim command in mac terminal

Tags: macos, vim, terminal

When I type `vim` command in terminal to start vim in terminal, it shows

> ImportError: No module named site,

and fails.
Also, the terminal window become in chaos, can't work right.
I looked for solutions for this problem, maybe it is caused because of something about python, but no solution is directly dealt with this problem.

[image: error image]

Comment: Have a look in your `vim` startup file `"$HOME/.vimrc"` to see if there is anything strange in there.

Comment: try `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE` and see if there is still any problems

Comment: To "fix" your terminal type: `reset` and press enter

Comment: vim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE let vim start working well, but vim still not

Comment: nothing strange in vimrc file because it works well in my another mac

Comment: Most probably some issue in your vimrc. Try opening vim after removing your vimrc.